# Q2:Why does this config code not work in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I will use instead of Document_Root in .htaccess??

Following is in my htttp.conf of my linux server.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)(/?)$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,15})(/?)$ /profile.php?fairid=$1$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,15})/([a-z]*)(/?)$ /$3.php?fairid=$1$2 [L]
```

But now I shifted my domain to shared server. So for running my site properly what changes will be needed in .htaccess in rewrite rules?

My .htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~laborfa2
RewriteCond %/~laborfa2/lf/main/com/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule /(.*)(/?)$ /~laborfa2/lf/main/com/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,15})(/?)$ /~laborfa2/lf/main/com/profile.php?fairid=$1$2 [L]
```

But it is not working. Please suggest the changes will be needed in .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

`REQUEST_FILENAME` already is an absolute file system path and prepending `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is wrong.

Additionally, when using mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file, Apache strips the per-directory path prefix from the requested URI path before testing the rules. And in case of the .htaccess file in the document root of the web server, it’s the leading `/` that’s stripped of. So your pattern must not begin with a leading slash like in the server or virtual host configuration.

So try this:

```
RewriteBase /~laborfa2/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}~laborfa2/lf/main/com/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)(/?)$ /lf/main/com/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,15})(/?)$ /lf/main/com/profile.php?fairid=$1 [L]
```